# Can Pyomo use Google's GLOP or CP-SAT solvers?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, or-tools, cp-sat

Pyomo can be linked with several solvers
Open source and commercial ones.

I was wondering if Pyomo can be linked with  Google's GLOP or CP-SAT solvers?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We have never been in contact with the pyomo team. So I guess no.

Furthermore, CP-SAT has a more complex API (scheduling, routing) and I do not know if pyomo had dealt with these constraints before.

Furthermore, or-tools offers an python API for both solvers.